# How to link shared library in Ament Tool ROS

Tags: c++, linux, ros, ros2

I am building my packages with ROS ament tools. structure is as below

```
LibA (build as shared library)

LibB (depends on LibA & build as shared library)

AppB (depends on LinB)
```

in package.xml of LibB. I specified dependency as ...

```
package.xml (under dir LibB)

<build_depend>libA</build_depend>
```

in package.xml of AppB. I specified dependency as ...

```
package.xml (under dir AppB)

<build_depend>libA</build_depend>
<build_depend>libB</build_depend>
```

Now build order is correct as ..

```
# Topological order
 - libA
 - libB
 - AppB
```

Now issue starts when bulding AppB, and it can't find link for LibA and LibB.

**Question**

How can I link LibA to LibB ? (what syntax should I use)

How can I link LibA,LibB to AppB ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use `ament_export` in LibA `CMakeLists.txt`, [this page](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/) from ROS2 should help

```
# CMakeLists.txt for LibA
add_library(LibA SHARED src/LibA.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(LibA rclcpp)
ament_export_interfaces(export_LibA HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
ament_export_libraries(LibA)
ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_dependencies(
    ament_cmake
    rclcpp
)
install(
    TARGETS LibA
    EXPORT export_LibA
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(
    DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION include
)
```

and then in `CMakeLists.txt` from LibB you should have

```
# CMakeLists.txt for LibB
find_package(LibA REQUIRED)
add_library(LibB SHARED src/LibB.cpp)
target_include_directories(LibB PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
ament_target_dependencies(LibB
    rclcpp
    LibA
)
ament_export_libraries(LibB)
ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_dependencies(
    rclcpp
    LibA
)
install(
    TARGETS LibB
    EXPORT export_LibB
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(
    DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION include
)
```

To use `LibA` and `LibB` with `AppB`, I think you need to use `ament_target_dependencies` with `LibB` as argument and then use `add_executable()` function

I think you could change the `<build_depend>` tag for `<depend>`

Comment: ament_export_interfaces is depricated. could you update your answer ?